# How to test if a decorator is decorating a method or a function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am just wondering for a decorator how can it know if a the function it is decorating is a method, a function, a static method, or a class method? What is the most robust way to distinguish these four different types inside a decorator?

Comment: methods *are functions*. However, staticmethod and classmethod are instances of those respective classes.

Comment: but I assume there is a way to distinguish if the methods from functions? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @BobFang No, there is no way. In theory, you can define a function outside of a class and assign it as a method to that class after the class definition.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a code snipped solving your problem using `__qualname__`:

```
def callable_type(callable):
    what = type(callable).__name__
    name = callable.__qualname__
    if what == "function" and "." in name:
        return "method"
    elif what == "function":
        return "function"
    elif what == "type":
        return "class"
```

It is quite hacky but works in most cases.

Comment: This fails for nested functions and other cases where `__qualname__` has a `.` without the function being a method (or for cases where `__qualname__` has no `.` despite being a method, such as methods defined outside a class and then attached to the class).

Comment: It also fails for classes with a metaclass other than `type`. For example, any abstract class will have a non-`type` metaclass (usually `abc.ABCMeta`), resulting in `what != "type"`.